# Get 20% of lines in File randomly

Tags: shell

This is my code:

```
nb_lignes=`wc -l $1 | cut -d " " -f1`
for i in $(seq $nb_lignes)
do
m=`head $1 -n $i | tail -1`
//command
done
```

Please how can i change it to get Get 20% of lines in File randomly to apply "command" on each line ?
20% or 40% or 60 % (it's a parameter)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will randomly get 20% of the lines in the file:

```
awk -v p=20 'BEGIN {srand()} rand() <= p/100' filename
```

So something like this for the whole solution (assuming bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
pct="${2:-20}"     # specify percentage
while read line; do
  : # some command with "$line"
done < <(awk -v p="$pct" 'BEGIN {srand()} rand() <= p/100'  "$filename")
```

If you're using a shell without command substitution (the `<(...)` bit), you can do this - but the body of the loop won't be able to have any side effects in the outer script (e.g. any variables it sets won't be set anymore once the loop completes):

```
#!/bin/sh
filename="$1"
pct="${2:-20}"     # specify percentage
awk -v p="$pct" 'BEGIN {srand()} rand() <= p/100'  "$filename" | 
 while read line; do
   : # some command with "$line"
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file=$1
nb_lignes=$(wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1)
num_lines_to_get=$((20*${nb_lignes}/100)) 
for (( i=0; i < $num_lines_to_get; i++))
do
  line=$(head -$((${RANDOM} % $nb_lignes)) $file | tail -1)
  echo "$line"
done
```

Note that `${RANDOM}` only generates numbers less than 32768 so this approach won't work for large files.

If you have `shuf` installed, you can use the following to get a random line instead of using `$RANDOM`.

```
line=$(shuf -n 1 $file)
```

Comment: do
  line=$(head -$((${RANDOM} % $nb_lignes)) $file | tail -1)
  echo "$line"
done  --> Are these lines distincts or could be duplicated ?

Comment: Please could you explain more your idea, i want them distincts not duplicated , thank you

Comment: i ask if we can chage the for by while, store the "line" in a table and we verify in eatch iteration if it's used or not , what's your opinon please ?

Comment: yes, you can do that. Store the lines in an array and check if the line is present in the array in each iteration.

Comment: can you guide me please i'm beginner with script shell

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with awk.see below:

```
awk -v b=20 '{a[NR]=$0}END{val=((b/100)*NR)+1;for(i=1;i<val;i++)print a[i]}' all.log
```

the above command prints 20% of all the lines starting from begining of the file.

you just have to change the value of b on command line to get the required % of lines.
tested below:

```
> cat temp
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
> awk -v b=10 '{a[NR]=$0}END{val=((b/100)*NR)+1;for(i=1;i<val;i++)print a[i]}' temp
1
> awk -v b=20 '{a[NR]=$0}END{val=((b/100)*NR)+1;for(i=1;i<val;i++)print a[i]}' temp
1
2
>
```

Comment: OP asked for random lines, not always the top 20%.

Answer (score 0):

shuf will produce the file in a randomized order; if you know how many lines you want, you can give that to the -n parameter. No need to get them one at a time. So:

```
shuf -n $(( $(wc -l < $FILE) * $PCT / 100 )) "$file" |
while read line; do 
  # do something with $line
done
```

shuf comes standard with GNU/Linux distros afaik.